# Pass data from index method of one controller to create of another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I generated a devise model User, and I also have a Conversation controller. I'm showing all users, except the logged in one, and I'm trying to create a new Conversation between user1 and user2, but I get redirected to the index method of the Conversation Controller, not the create one. I understood from this link that making a post from one controller to another is a bad idea [Rails: How to POST internally to another controller action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592353/rails-how-to-post-internally-to-another-controller-action).

I've also tried to make a send_message method inside the Users controller and define it as a post in routes, but I get redirected to the show method of the Users controller.

What is the clean way of doing this?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.where.not(id: current_user.id)
  end

  def send_message
    # @conversation = Conversation.new(conversation_params)
    # if @conversation.save
    #
    # end
  end

end
```

index.html.erb

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
<h1> User's index </h1>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Created</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= time_ago_in_words(user.created_at) %> ago</td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <%= link_to 'Send', conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: user.id) %>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>


</div>
```

Edit:

```
private
  def conversation_params
     params.require(:conversation).permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
  end


<ActionController::Parameters {"_method"=>"post", "authenticity_token"=>"394MDmcVVelccU//8ISYeqmk146exYc6G7SrrAhbCA/yQ/K8KTpSn/0EkXlZ4hB/g==", "recipient_id"=>"1", "sender_id"=>"3", "controller"=>"conversations", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `link_to` helper sends GET request. You can do it with adding `method: :post` to its options.

```
<%= link_to 'Send', path, method: :post %>
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right. No idea how I didn't think of that. But is this the right way to go? As I posted that link that says that I shouldn't pass params between controllers? Or is that referring to something else?

Comment: You don't need pass params between controllers :) You should send your request to ConversationsController#create action (conversations_path)

Comment: The params go to the create method, but my conversations_params.permit is complaining `param is missing or the value is empty: conversation`. I updated with the private method and with what I'm sending. Should I send a new conversation?

Comment: Yeah, it's reasonable because i suppose in your conversation controller you have something like: `params.require(:conversation).permit(...)`. So if you have this code it means that you have new conversation action, may be you should just redirect from users#index to conversations#new when you click 'Send'? Sorry, may be I'm wrong, it's difficult to understand your app remotely ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect to new_converstion_path instead of conversations_path. And link by default sends GET not POST request.

Comment: Thanks. I update as Sergei said with `method: :post` and it s now working.