# Redirecting to BarsController#create from FoosController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, http, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I read in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10592523/2909897) that it's bad practice to `redirect_to` a different controller's `create` action.

I'm trying to implement a `Create Foo and Bar` button in my form on `Foos#new`.

`Foo` uses the information from the form and `Bar` can use `Foo`'s id to `Foo.find(params[:foo_id])` to get the information from `Foo` it needs. It makes sense to me that I should do something like:

```
if params['route_to']['bar']
  redirect_to controller: :bars, action: :create, foo_id: @foo.id
else
  redirect_to foos_path
end
```

at the end of my `Foos#create`.

- Am I making an architectural mistake?
- What is a better way?
- How do I tell `redirect_to` to `POST` instead of `GET`? Because right now I'm submitting a `GET` when I want a `POST`
- Should I use [concerns](https://www.sitepoint.com/dry-off-your-rails-code-with-activesupportconcerns/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a Bar object after creating a Foo object? I'd just do that in the create method for Foo.

Something like

```
def create
    @foo = Foo.new(foo_params)
    if @foo.save
      @bar = Bar.new
      @bar.attribute1 = @foo.attribute_bar_needs
      @bar.save
    end
end
```

Even better, if a bar object needs to be created after every Foo object, then I'd make an after_create callback in the Foo model to do so instead of doing it in a controller.